# Google doesn't recognise @type in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Why does Google Structured Data Testing Tool show an error in this case?

[image: Error in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool]

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool is not a general structured data validator. It only recognizes terms from vocabularies which Google makes use of (e.g., [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) and the deprecated Data-Vocabulary.org).

You are using the [GS1](https://www.gs1.org/voc/) vocabulary, which doesn’t seem to be one of the vocabularies supported by Google.

All terms from other vocabularies produce this error. It’s perfectly fine to use such terms, so simply ignore these errors.

Comment: ok, thx a lot but when i add "@type" = ["Offer", "gs1:Offer"] only first type is incorrect, the secound one is correct. Why?

Comment: @Olejs: Would be best to ask this in a separate question, where you include a minimal JSON-LD example (as code block, not as image) that gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

You might try it on the [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org), which is not so tightly bound to schema.org or datavocabulary. IIRC, it doesn't have built-in knowledge of GS1, but this could be added fairly reasonably. Issues and pull-requests at http://github.com/structured-data/linter.